# Lightweight webserver with SSPI authentification

Tags: nginx, kerberos, windows, web-server

I'm looking for a fast, lightweight web server (for example nginx or lighttpd) which supports authentication to a Microsoft Kerberos authentication server (SSPI). This webserver must run under Windows and Linux.

There is a nice module for the Apache server (sspi_auth_module), but the performance gain of lightweight webservers seems very promising.

Modules I've found for the nginx server:

- [http-gsspi-auth-nginx-module](https://github.com/joekhoobyar/http-gsspi-auth-nginx-module) which needs a recompilation which needs recompilation of the webserver (Might not work again with newer server versions?)
- spnego-http-auth-nginx-module which does not support SSPI but only GSSAPI. I'm not shure if the authentication works over GSSAPI as the Microsoft documentation only explains the [GSSAPI authentication in the other direction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380496%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Are there other options? What would be your choice?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic for multiple reasons.

Comment: Could you please be a bit more precise?

Comment: No.  You're responding to an auto-generated comment created when I voted to close this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but the performance gain of lightweight webservers seems very promising.

While nginx is certainly faster than Apache, it ain't *that* much faster. Web applications usually take up 90%+ of the processing time, meaning the web server is usually the *last* place you want to go looking for performance if you want to make an appreciable difference.

> Are there other options? What would be your choice?

My choice would be working with what I'm already familiar with, or what I *know I can get to work*.